# Trying to stream picamera with a raspberry pi zero w using flask. But the camera fails to start due to being "out of resources"

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi-zero, picamera

Ok. So this problem has been going on for a few days and is driving me mental. I am using a Raspberry Pi Zero W using 32Bit Raspberry Pi OS Lite.

My goal:
I want to host and stream the video feed from the Zero - *Not sure if it can handle it and this may be causing the issue?* - The camera works as I can take a photo and save it using the zero.

The issue is when `camera = picamera.PiCamera()` is run, the camera fails to start and causes the error.

Here is the python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import picamera
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure the PiCamera
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 24

# Define a generator function that yields the frames from the camera
def gen(camera):
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1) # wait for the camera to warm up
        frame = camera.capture(format='jpeg', use_video_port=True)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

# Define the route that will stream the video
@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(camera), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

# Define the main route that will display the video in the browser
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

The error:

```
mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV): ENOSPC
mmal: mmal_port_enable: failed to enable connected port (vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV))0x1e4e370 (ENOSPC)
mmal: mmal_connection_enable: output port couldn't be enabled
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources
```

I have tried clearing up RAM, reinstalling the OS and restarting the Zero. I made sure the camera is connected correctly. However the result was the same each time.

I also made sure no other programs are using the camera at the same time.

Comment: If your intent is to get 24 fps, move the `time.sleep(0.1)` above the `while True:` That may or may not have anything to do with resource exhaustion.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I didn't even notice it was within the loop! I have moved that outside now, thanks. However the error still persists. 

I am not sure if the code in the loop will even run due to the crash happening at the start.